# AD groups and ms SQL security: is this default behavior?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a question regarding security in MS SQL Server (right now, I'm trying this on a SQL 2016).

Scenario:
User `AD\testuser` is in both AD security groups (`AD\testgroup1` and `AD\testgroup2`).

- A new database `testDB` is created.
- A new table `Testtable` is created in `testDB`.
- Login is created for `AD\testgroup1`
- User `AD\testgroup1` is created in database `testDB`
- User `AD\testgroup1` have `select` permission on table `testTable`.

We log in as `AD\testuser`, user only has select on `TestTable` --> as expected

- Login is created for `AD\testgroup2`
- User `AD\testgroup2` is created in database `testDB`
- User `AD\testgroup2` granted for `select, insert, update on table` `testTable`.

We log in as `testuser`, user has `select`, `insert`, `update` on `TestTable`  --> as expected

Login `AD\testgroup2` is removed from server (so `AD\testgroup2` is still a use rin the database, but login is removed)

We log in as `testuser`, user has `select`, `insert`, `update` (we were under the impression this should only be `select`)

Access for user `AD\testgroup2` is revoked in database `testDB`

We log in as `testuser`, user has `select, insert, update` (we were under the impression this should only be `select`)

User `AD\testgroup2` is dropped in database `testDB`. When we test with same user, user only has `select` --> as expected

Why do we still get the highest permissions, even when AD group is removed from logins, and disabled in DB users?

Comment: Check if something has gone wrong with the SID mapping maybe? https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-logins-users-security-identifiers-sids/          
  USE <yourdb> 
SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals
SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we still get the highest permissions, even when AD group is
>   removed from logins, and disabled in DB users?

This is because `testuser` is a member of both `AD\testgroup1` and `AD\testgroup2` and both those groups exist in the database with object permissions, resulting in cumulative object permissions for the `testuser` role member.

There is no requirement that a login exists for a Windows group database user; one can add a Windows group database user and grant permissions to that user regardless of whether a login for the Windows group exists. Permissions granted to groups will be honored for role members even if a corresponding login doesn't exist, as you've observed.

Without an individual login for `testuser`, the user must be a member of at least one Windows group with a login to connect to the server. This was `AD\testgroup1` in your example after you dropped the `AD\testgroup2` login. But the user still had object permisssions granted to `AD\testgroup2` until you dropped the user.

Comment: Thanks, that made it very clear for me